# Why my React Router is not working?

Tags: javascript, react-router, reactjs, react-routing

I am working on an example and making react router.Below is my code. But when I am running my code it is giving me error "Unexpected syntax" on the opening line of < Router > .Below is the code:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Base = require('./components/base.jsx');
var PageOne = require('./components/pageone.jsx');
var PageTwo = require('./components/pageTwo.jsx');

var Route = function(){
     <Router>
        <Route path="/PageOne" component= {PageOne}></Route>
         <Route path="/pageTwo" component= {PageTwo}></Route>
     </Router>
     }

module.exports = Route;
```

Could anyone please check and let me know where I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Neha

Comment: You could be over-writing `Route` because you are both defining it as an import for `ReactRouter.Route` and you are using it as a variable for `module.exports`

Comment: Otherwise, the file doesn't like `jsx` for some reason.

Comment: Hey, I did the change in name but still no luck :(

Comment: are you simply missing a `return` for that function?

Comment: Can you also show js code that is actually running?

Comment: Here is the code : https://github.com/Neha/React-skeleton

Comment: You just need to add return statement in Route function and add `initial={true}` whichever component you want to land as a first page

`var Route = function(){
     return (<Router>
        <Route path="/PageOne" component= {PageOne}></Route>
         <Route path="/pageTwo" component= {PageTwo}></Route>
     </Router>)
     }`